# How to find surface normal of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

If I have a triangle with $3$ points $P_1, P_2,$ and $P_3$, each with $x, y,$ and $z$ coordinates, how do I find the surface normal $N$ in $x, y,$ and $z$ such that

$$(N_x)^2+(N_y)^2+(N_z)^2 = 1$$

I'm looking for a simple formula that uses values like $x_1$, $x_2$, or $y_3$, and doesn't involve complicated equations or cross products.

Comment: What are Nx,Ny,Nz?

Comment: @SalechAlhasov x, y, and z coordinates of the surface normal vector.

Comment: In general the $N$ for each of $x, y$ and $z$ will be different. One thing you could do is write $v = P_1 - P_2$ and $w = P_2 - P_3$ to get two vectors ,then take the cross product $u = v \times w$; then $u\cdot (x, y, z) = d$, where $d = u\cdot P_1 = u\cdot P_2 = u\cdot P_3$ ($P_1, P_2, P_3$ are on the plane.)

Comment: @snarski Could you simplify that?

Comment: @acer sorry, not unless you are a little clearer about what you are asking. What is $N$? Why does it have to = 1 for all $N$ being equal? And by surface normal, do you mean the normal vector to the plane in which the triangle lives?

Comment: @snarski N is the surface normal vector, and the surface normal is the normal vector to the plane in which the triangle lives. Nx+Ny+Nz has to equal 1 for simplicity purposes.

Comment: if $N$ is a vector and $x,y z$ are numbers and $Nx+Ny+Nz = 1$, the lfet hand side of the equation is a vector and the right hand side is a scalar. Do you mean $\vec{N}\cdot\vec{X}$, where $\vec{X} = (x,y,z)$?

Comment: Cross products aren't that complicated...

Comment: Why do you want the components to add to 1?  Do you want the normal vector to be unit instead (which would involve *squaring* the components)?

Comment: For simplicity reasons.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The cross product of two sides of the triangle equals the surface normal. So, if vector $V$ = $P_2$ - $P_1$, vector $W$ = $P_3$ - $P_1$, and vector $N$ is the surface normal, then:

$N_x = (V_y * W_z) - (V_z * W_y)$

$N_y = (V_z * W_x) - (V_x * W_z)$

$N_z = (V_x * W_y) - (V_y * W_x)$

If $A$ is the new vector whose length is 1, then:

$A_x = \frac {N_x}{\sqrt((N_x)^2 + (N_y)^2 + (N_z)^2)}$

$A_y = \frac {N_y}{\sqrt {(N_x)^2 + (N_y)^2 + (N_z)^2}}$

$A_z = \frac {N_z}{\sqrt {(N_x)^2 + (N_y)^2 + (N_z)^2}}$

My sources:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)

Comment: What will you do if $N_x+N_y+N_z=0$?

Comment: If $N_x+N_y+N_z=0$ then the condition that their sum equal 1, as the OP asked for, can't be met anyway.

Comment: $N_x + N_y + N_z$ can't equal $0$ unless the triangle's points are all the same.

Comment: Oh really? What about the triangle whose vertices are $(0,0,0)$, $(1,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$?

Comment: @ℝⁿ. That's another exception, but I won't be using those triangles anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @The Great Duck, back when I made this answer I had not learned a lot about linear algebra yet.

Comment: Isn't a square root missing in the normalization?

Comment: @StephaneBersier yes, I will make an edit

Answer (score 9):

The general question can be written in python like this:

```
import numpy as np
p1 = np.array([0,0,5])
p2 = np.array([1,0,5])
p3 = np.array([0,1,5])

N = np.cross(p2-p1, p3-p1)
```

The 'normalized' sum of 1 can be attempted like this:

```
N = N / N.sum()
```

For the (0,0,0), (1,1,0), (0,0,1) example mentioned above, where the components add up to 0, the result silently degrades to `array([ inf, -inf, nan])`.

Comment: Please, this is Math SE, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is really cool, numpy is useful for more than I thought. Plus when I first asked this question it was exactly for this purpose—to be able to calculate the surface normal in a programming environment.

Comment: @scaaahu Given the nature of the question, a relation to computer graphics was not entirely unlikely, and many years later, computer graphics are precisely how I stumbled upon this question, so I don't see anything wrong with this answer at all.

Answer (score 7):

Let $P_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, $P_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and $P_3=(x_3,y_3,z_3)$. The normal vector to the triangle with these three points as its vertices is then given by the cross product $n=(P_2-P_1)\times (P_3-P_1)$. In matrix form, we then see that
$$n=\det\left(\left[\begin{matrix}i&j&k\\
x_2-x_1&y_2-y_1&z_2-z_1\\
x_3-x_1&y_3-y_1&z_3-z_1
\end{matrix}\right]\right)$$

$$=\left(\begin{matrix}(y_2-y_1)(z_3-z_1)-(y_3-y_1)(z_2-z_1)\\
(z_2-z_1)(x_3-x_1)-(x_2-x_1)(z_3-z_1)\\
(x_2-x_1)(y_3-y_1)-(x_3-x_1)(y_2-y_1)
\end{matrix}\right)$$

If you need that the sum of the coefficients of $\hat{n}$ equals 1, then set $\alpha$ equal to the sum of the coefficients of $n$ and then let $\hat{n}=\frac{1}{\alpha}n$. Obviously, if $\alpha=0$ then you will never be able to satisfy your condition as any scalar multiple of $n$ will have the same zero-sum of coefficients.