# Calculating the Surface Normal of a Triangle

Tags: triangles, 3d

If a point looks like this:

$$\textbf{point = [x, y, z]}$$

I have a triangle made up of these points:

$$p_a = [0.3333, 0, 0.05]$$
$$p_b = [0.4333, 0, 0.05]$$
$$p_c = [0.3317, 0.0327, 0.05]$$

I need to determine the surface normal for this triangle. I have no formal math training but from research online these are the steps I am following:

$$U = p_b - p_a$$
$$V = p_c - p_a$$

$$N_x = U_y \times V_z - U_z \times V_y $$
$$N_y = U_z \times V_x - U_x \times V_z $$
$$N_z = U_x \times V_y - U_y \times V_x $$
$$N = [0, 0, 0.00327]$$

Is this method correct? Looking at the results on a plot it doesn't seem correct to me and applying it to my real world use case it does not seem correct either.

My sources for my research are:

[How to find surface normal of a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305642/how-to-find-surface-normal-of-a-triangle)

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Calculating_a_Surface_Normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have gone into it extensively, I answer short:

$ U \times V $ a single cross product alone will do for the normal. Unit normal can be extracted by finding absolute value in the usual way if needed.

Comment: So my answer is right? N=[0,0,0.00327]

Comment: Yes, x,y components are = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your $N_x$ should be:

$$N_x = U_y \times V_z - U_z \times V_y $$

Comment: Oops, fixed that. It was a typo in my question. I am using the correct version in my calculations.